# How to print a formatting character out?

Tags: c, printf

How to print the formatting characters such as: `%p` out? A backslash doesn't do any good as it does with quotations(`""`). I tried it in a simple toy program and I suppose the value returned by it was garbage :
[image]

What I was trying to print was the statement :

```
With the formatting character %p and '&'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using double percentage i.e. `%%` will print single `%` for you:

```
printf("With the formatting character %%p and '&'\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

## include

int main(){

```
/* code */

printf("%s\n","With the formatting character %p and '&;");
```

}

Should print the proper string.